# Allow SharePoint Audit to Read only 1 week of SharePoint Site Report

Tags: auditing, farm-admin, spaudit, audit-log-reports, spauditeventtype

- I have very large site collection ,And Enabled Audit feature for it.
  My Server Performance is getting effected on Server ,As Audit is holding large
  amount of report .
- I would like to make audit to hold only last 1 week of SharePoint Site 
  Collection report

Can any one help me or guide me in Achieving this

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Configure audit settings, please checkout the following article

support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012

social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25428.sharepoint-2013-how-to-enable-the-audit-log.aspx

Additionally, you could also try this solution ( https://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/sharepoint-auditing.html ) which provides audit  reports.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the audit logs for one week, you have to [set the audit trimming option in SharePoint auditing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012).

However, the best practice is to store audit logs in a [SIEM](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/recommended-SIEMs/Default.aspx) (there are some free versions available too), where you can aggregate, analyze, find correlations etc from different audit log sources and generate reports and alerts.

To get the audit logs out of SharePoint and forward them to a SIEM, you can use a product like [LOGbinder for SharePoint](https://www.logbinder.com/Products/LOGbinderSP/). This way, as soon as the audit logs are transferred to your SIEM, they can be removed from SharePoint, freeing up database space.